# Justifying an inequality in a proof of Carathéodory's Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, outer-measure

In the proof below, how is the inequality

$$\lambda(G) \le \sum_n\sum_k\mu_0(F_{n,k})$$

justified?

---

[screenshot, transcribed below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv2Yn.png)

> A1.8. Proof of Carathéodory's Theorem.
> Recall that we need to prove the following.
> Let $S$ be a set, let $\Sigma_0$ be an algebra on $S$, and let
> $$
> \Sigma:=\sigma\left(\Sigma_0\right) .
> $$
> If $\mu_0$ is a countably additive map $\mu_0: \Sigma_0 \rightarrow[0, \infty]$, then there exists a measure $\mu$ on $(S, \Sigma)$ such that
> $$
> \mu=\mu_0 \text { on } \Sigma_0 .
> $$
> Proof. Step 1: Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of $S$. For $G \in \mathcal{G}$, define
> $$
> \lambda(G):=\inf \sum_n \mu_0\left(F_n\right),
> $$
> where the infimum is taken over all sequences $\left(F_n\right)$ in $\Sigma_0$ with $G \subseteq \bigcup_n F_n$. We now prove that
> (a) $\lambda$ is an outer measure on $(S, \mathcal{G})$.
> The facts that $\lambda(\emptyset)=0$ and $\lambda$ is increasing are obvious. Suppose that $\left(G_n\right)$ is a sequence in $\mathcal{G}$, such that each $\lambda\left(G_n\right)$ is finite. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. For each $n$, choose a sequence $\left(F_{n, k}: k \in \mathbf{N}\right)$ of elements of $\Sigma_0$ such that
> $$
> G_n \subseteq \bigcup_k F_{n, k}, \quad \sum_k \mu_0\left(F_{n, k}\right)<\lambda\left(G_n\right)+\varepsilon 2^{-n} .
> $$
> Then $G:=\bigcup G_n \subseteq \bigcup_n \bigcup_k F_{n, k}$, so that
> $$
> \lambda(G) \leq \sum_n \sum_k \mu_0\left(F_{n, k}\right)<\sum_n \lambda\left(G_n\right)+\varepsilon .
> $$
> Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we have proved result (a).

Comment: $\lambda$ is defined as an infimum over all possible sums, so cannot be larger than one specially chosen sum

Comment: I didn't really check all the details but I guess ummmm it's an infimum of sums over all sequences so it's $\le$ sum for any possible sequence?

Answer (score 1):

What is trivial from the definition of $\lambda$ is that, arranging the (countably many) $F_{n,k}$ into a sequence $(F_m)$, we have
$$\lambda(G) \le \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}F_m.$$
What was not clear to me is why the above series is to equal
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}F_{n,k}.$$

---

I realize now that the equality can be proven as follows:
\begin{equation}
\tag{$*$}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}F_m = \sum_{m\in \mathbb{N}}F_m = \sum_{(n,k)\in \mathbb{N}^2}F_{n,k} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}F_{n,k}
\end{equation}
where the third equality in $(*)$ follows from Tonelli's Theorem for Series, and the two expressions in the middle are defined by
$$\sum_{\alpha \in A}x_{\alpha} := \sup\left\{\sum_{\alpha \in F}x_{\alpha} : \text{ for a finite subset $F$ of $A$}\right\}$$
so that the second equality in $(*)$ is trivial and the first is a standard result. All of this is treated at the beginning of Tao's *An Introduction to Measure Theory*.

Comment: 'What was not clear to me is why the above series is to equal' - You know Gasai this is a far more specific question than your original question?

Comment: @BCLC you are completely right. It was my fault for not asking a more concrete question from the begining. I will try to me more concise in the future (:

Comment: ah ok thanks. also i think it's precise / specific not concise.